# Path already exists and is not empty

Tags: cordova

I am using cordova to create an app. I have installed cordova using:
npm install -g cordova

When I write: cordova create MyApp, I get this error message:
Path already exists and is not empty. Kindly advise.

Comment: that simply means that the path "MyApp" already exists and is not empty.

Comment: How do I create a path for a new cordova application?

Comment: the directory "MyApp" already exists, you have to use a different name or a different path. the path is created by cordova.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal (e.g. Command prompt/cmd.exe on Windows, or Bash Shell on Linux or MacOS) in a directory that does *NOT* contain a sub-directory named `MyCordovaProjectFolder` and enter a command according to the following example:

```
cordova create MyCordovaProjectFolder com.test.cordova.myapp "My App Name"
```

Meaning of the arguments:

- `create`: Operation to be performed by Cordova, namely creation of a new project.
- `MyCordovaProjectFolder`: New folder to be created.
- `com.test.cordova.myapp`: ID of the new app (must be globally unique).
- `"My App Name"`: Display name of the app to be created (e.g. name of app on homescreen of Android device).

After the successful execution of this command a new folder `MyCordovaProjectFolder` with an Cordova project should have been created. Enter `cd MyCordovaProjectFolder` to change into this folder to enter the further commands, e.g. `cordova platform add android` to add Android as target OS for the Cordova app and `cordova build android` to build the app (i.e. to generate the APK file for an Android app).